# move_uploaded_file creating unaccessible (403 forbidden) files under nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I've created a simple upload script in php that takes a file submitted from a form and puts it in the desired directory. The problem is that, for some reason, when you try to show this file in the browser, the server answers with a 403 - Forbidden message. In fact I modified the script so it first makes a copy of the file from the tmp folder and then moves it with a different name:

```
copy($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$new_file_name);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'm_'.$new_file_name);
```

So if i.e. I upload file.jpg, it creates file.jpg (copied) and m_file.jpg (moved). On the server, both files are in the same folder and look identical, **with the same permissions, user and group**, except that domain.com/file.jpg shows the image and domain.com/m_file.jpg returns a 403 error.

If I disable nginx and make it work with apache, it all works fine, though. I revised nginx conf files but there's nothing strange (in fact is using the default config)

**Update:**
strangely, seems that the problem only shows up in configurations where the PHP version is greater than 5.3 and is executed as "fpm application served by nginx". So, it works fine with 5.3.3 but does not work with php 5.5 or 7, unless you execute it as a "fastCGI app served by Apache"

Comment: I don't quite understand, how do it can work fine, while you stop your web server? Also, are you sure browser does not show you a cached version of image when you requesting domain.com/file.jpg? Possible it's also inaccessible

Comment: Sorry I meant that it works when using apache (The server defaults to it when nginx is not active), after restarting it and everything, not when it's stopped (of course). Also, yes, I'm completely sure that it's not a cached version

Comment: Perhaps nginx static file caching? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13116771/2908724

Comment: nope, turning sendfile off in nginx.conf and restarting the server does not make any difference